# Adding a gem dependency to gemspec that requires a git url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rails-engines

I am looking to add a gem dependency to an engine that I am creating. I tried adding it in the same way that I would add it in a Gemfile but it doesn't appear to be working. How would I add this in the .gemspec

Gem I want to add

```
  s.add_dependency 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', git: "https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter"
```

Error I am getting

```
Illformed requirement [{:git=>"https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter"}] from
/Users/lovell/rails/my_engine/my_engine.gemspec:25:in `block in <main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be out of luck; the `:git` property you can set in your Gemfile [comes from Bundler, and isn't supported in "native" RubyGems](http://bundler.io/v1.2/git.html). As it's not supported in RubyGems, you can't require this from your Gemspec.

Comment: Ah bummer. Ok. This doesn't work if I add this to my main applications Gemfile so I will just make sure that it's documented that it is required there. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that this does work if I add these gems to my Gemfile in the main application.